# How to pass the file path command line arguments to check code is working fine or not in Python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have written the below code using args and added the path variable but I am not able to test this code because I am unable to run my script.

How to pass the file path command line arguments to check code is working fine or not in Python jupyter notebook?

```
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date,time
import sys
import os
import datetime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Tractive_missing_campaign')
parser.add_argument("--SP_File",
                    help="Add path of your SP file",type=Path)
parser.add_argument("--File2",
                    help="Add path of your Datorama file",type=Path)
parser.add_argument("Missing_Campaign_File",help="Add path where you want to save your file",type=Path)

args = parser.parse_args()

## reading file path
Sp_Report = os.chdir(args.SP_File)
 
if not Sp_Report.exists():
    raise ValueError(f"I did not find the SP file at {Sp_Report}")
try:
    with open(Sp_Report, "r+") as csvfile:
        file_df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
except Exception as ex:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
    print(message)

## Datorama Report of Campaign keys
Report = os.chdir(args.File2)
 
if not Report.exists():
    raise ValueError(f"I did not find the file at {Report}")
try:
    with open(Report, "r+") as csvfile:
        file_df2 = pd.read_csv(csvfile,usecols = ['Campaign Key'])
except Exception as ex:
    template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
    message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
    print(message)

print(file_df2.shape)    


output_path = args.Missing_Campaign_File

for slicer_column_value in slicer_column_values:
    temporary_df = left_merged[(left_merged['currency'] == slicer_column_value) & (left_merged['Match'] == Match_Values)]
    PartnerWiseFileName = os.path.join(output_path,'Missing_camp_{}_{}_{}_data.xlsx'.format(slicer_column_value, start_date, end_date))
    print(temporary_df.shape)    
    temporary_df.to_excel(PartnerWiseFileName, index = False)
print("Job Complete")
```

Can someone let me know which query I need to use to run this script? I tried using the following:

```
%%!
python Tractive_missing.ipynb --SP_File 'file1.csv' --Report2 'csv2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the command line arguments at the top of the notebook, if you don't care about actually running it from the command line. Consider this example cell:

```
%%python - "Running with Arguments"

from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("message")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.message)
```

The top line passes "Running with Arguments" as first positional argument to the jupyter notebook, so you can adjust that line to run with the arguments that you want to use for your notebook. You can then also run this example from command line using `jupyter execute` (https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html#using-a-command-line-interface) although this still won't allow you to specify the arguments on the command line specifically but still embedded in the notebook itself. If you actually want to run a script in command line simply convert it to a proper python script https://mljar.com/blog/convert-jupyter-notebook-python/